# How to read two separate CSV files in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm trying to upload two separate csv files and then do a "join" between the two in javascript. I was able to read both files and assigned them to an object but now I don't know how to pass both objects to a function for me to combine the data based of the same named column to transform my data.

```html
<form id="categoryform">
  <input type="file" id="projectCsvFileInput" multiple><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```js
categoryform.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const projectFile = projectCsvFileInput.files;

  // loop through each file
  for (let i = 0, len = projectFile.length; i < len; i++) {
    const file = projectFile[i];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    var project = {}
    var participants = {}

    reader.onload = (function(f) {
      return function(event) {
        let result = event.target.result;

        // separate out file data into separate obj
        if (result.includes('Project Name')) {
          project = csvToArr(result, ",");
        } else {
          participants = csvToArr(result, ",");
        }
      };
    })(file);

    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
  });
  
  function csvToArr(stringVal, splitter) {
    const [keys, ...rest] = stringVal
      .trim()
      .split("\n")
      .map((item) => item.split(splitter));

    const formedArr = rest.map((item) => {
    const object = {};
    keys.forEach((key, index) => {
      object[key.replace('\r','')] = item.at(index).replace('\r','').replace('\"','').replace('/S','');
    });
    
    return object;
  });

  return formedArr;
}
```

Comment: PSA: It's 2024 and time to use `let` and `const` in preference to `var`.

Comment: Why not `projectFile.forEach(file => { ... })`?

Comment: Create promises for reading each file, and use `Promise.all()` to perform an action when all the files have been read. This can pass the array of results to the comparison function.

Comment: Maybe you should consider a third party library for reading and parsing the CSV files? [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) is a small and efficient example of such a library. It is promise based and can deal with multi-line fields in the file too.